# Add section (add_settings_section) to a custom page (add_submenu_page)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, admin, menus

I have a plugin page created with `add_submenu_page`, I want to add a new section there but nothing happens:

```
add_submenu_page('parent', 'Foo', 'Foo', 'manage_options', 'foo-settings', 'anothercallback');
add_settings_section('foo-settings-section', 'Settings', 'acallback', 'foo-settings');
```

What's the right call to use it in a custom page? Do you have a complete example?

Comment: Do you have an "acallback" function defined?

Comment: Yes, i have it defined.

Comment: Do you get *any* output? i.e. do you get your `add_settings_section()` callback text output? How is your `add_submenu_page()` callback defined? Can we see that code?

Comment: Actually I've used an inline function definition (param, function () { echo 'here'; }, param); I'm running PHP 5.3. Thanks

Comment: Can you post all relevant code? Otherwise, it will be incredibly difficult to figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `add_settings_section()` function simply registers a form section with a certain slug with WordPress. In order to get the section and all the fields you've added to it to display on a certain menu page, you need to include the `do_settings_sections($sections-slug)` method in the menu's callback. This is, of course, assuming you are using the Settings API, which `add_settings_section` is part of.

Example:

```
function plugin_admin_init() {
     //All callbacks must be valid names of functions, even if provided functions are blank
     register_setting( 'option_group', 'option_name', 'sanitize_callback' );
     add_settings_section( 'section_id', 'section_title', 'section_callback', 'section_page_type' );
     add_settings_field( 'field_id', 'field_title', 'field_callback', 'section_page_type', 'section_id' );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'plugin_admin_init' );

function add_menus() {
     add_menu_page( 'menu_page_title', 'menu_title', 'menu_capability', 'menu_slug', 'menu_callback');
     add_submenu_page( 'menu_slug', 'submenu_page_title', 'submenu_title', 'submenu_capability', 'submenu_slug', 'submenu_callback' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_menus' );

function submenu_callback() {
     ?>
     <div class='wrap'>
          <h2>Settings</h2>
          <form method='post' action='options.php'>
          <?php 
               /* 'option_group' must match 'option_group' from register_setting call */
               settings_fields( 'option_group' );
               do_settings_sections( 'section_page_type' );
          ?>
               <p class='submit'>
                    <input name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' class='button-primary' value='<?php _e("Save Changes") ?>' />
               </p>
          </form>
     </div>
     <?php
}
```

I did my best to keep all the parameter names unique, so you should be able to pick them apart and trace where they go. The Settings API gets very specific about what needs to go where, so make sure you have that all right. Also, keep in mind that I omitted all the callback functions from this example, but in reality they are necessary.

Comment: I do have this call too :(

Comment: @thom 
Ok, here's a full example generalized from some working code I have.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was with do_settings_section's parameter.

Comment: The only situation where do_settings_sections($sections_slug) is not necessary, to exhibit sections previously added to a submenu page, is when you add your sections to a pre-existing submenu page, like those in Settings menu (general, writing, reading, discussion, media, permalink).

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem, in your `add_submenu_page()` callback:

```
settings_fields( 'option_group' );
do_settings_section( 'section_page_type' );
```

For `settings_fields()`:

- You need to use the `$optiongroup` parameter you passed to `register_setting()`.

For `do_settings_sections()`:

- The function is `do_settings_sections()`, **not** `do_settings_section()` (note plural)
- You need to pass the `$pageid` parameter you passed to `add_submenu_page()`.

### EDIT

Er, nevermind. I was responding to someone else's answer, which I misread as the actual callback function markup. The answers here may or may not apply; we still need to see the full code, including callbacks.